How do I retrieve the current Tenant ID from FilamentPHP?
I have a FilamentPHP application with multi-tenancy enabled. I'm trying to create a link in my Filament navigation that contains the ID of the Tenant I'm currently connected to.
Do you know how I can retrieve the ID of the current Tenant in order to then add a link like /ID/settings in my Filament navigation ?
Thanks,
I've tried to consult the documentation, but I can't seem to find anything that would allow me to retrieve the Tenant ID from the AdminPanelProvider file (into which I'm going to insert my custom navigation element).

Can you not utilize getTentant() as per the documentation?
I assume this gives you a Tenant modal of some sorts?

Just as @geertjanknapen said you can use getTenant() as shown in the docs.
use Filament\Facades\Filament;

$tenant_id = Filament::getTenant()->id;

But i think you looking for this registering custom navigation items
